# Get n level parent category from child category in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, categories

I have to use 2 level categories in laravel 5.2, so my database structure will look like below for table: categories

[category  table with some sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bRSB.png)

Currently i am able to get the parent category to only one level with use of below relation

```
public function ParentCategory() 
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','parent_category','category_id');
}
```

and my query to get the listing of child to 2nd category is

```
$subcategorydata = Category::with('ParentCategory')->where("category_level","=","2")->get();
```

So i want all parent category upto N level from child category.

Any help will really appreciated.

Comment: you can do category::with('parent','parent.parent','parent.parent.parent')

Comment: @AmirBar this one works ;)

Comment: @softnayr I am glad I was able to assist you :)

Comment: @AmirBar yep. simple, straightforward solution. I didn't find it in the documentation. Or, is it there?